# Shift bar locations on multi-bar bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

much searching has not yielded a working solution to a python matplotlib problem. I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#MWE plot
T = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n = len(T)
d1 = list(zip([500]*n, [250]*n))
d2 = list(zip([250]*n, [125]*n))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1, index=T)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2, index=T)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

df1.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, align='edge', width=-0.4, ax=ax)
df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, align='edge', width=0.4, ax=ax)    
plt.show()
```

Generates:
[Shifted Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agYtA.png)

No matter what parameters I play around with, that first bar is cut off on the left.  If I only plot a single bar (i.e. not clusters of bars), the bars are not cut off and in fact there is nice even white space on both sides.

I hard-coded the data for this MWE; however, I am trying to find a generic way to ensure the correct alignment since I will likely produce a LOT of these plots with varying numbers of items on the x axis and potentially a varying number of bars in each cluster.

How do I shift the bars so that the they are spaced correctly on the x axis with even white space?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the width that you put in your plots. Put some `xlim`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#MWE plot
T = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n = len(T)
d1 = list(zip([500]*n, [250]*n))
d2 = list(zip([250]*n, [125]*n))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1, index=T)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2, index=T)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

df1.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, align='edge', width=-0.4, ax=ax)
df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, align='edge', width=0.4, ax=ax)   
plt.xlim(-.4,5.4) 
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Hope it works!

Comment: That did work but....how did you know what numbers to use?  I get that the bar width factored in, but how would you know that overall limits should be a total of 5?

Comment: The `-.4` comes from the width of your `df1.plot()` and the `5.4` from the another. You need to assume that your array is plotted taking into account your indices, not what you put in the `T` array. So `-.4` comes from `0.0-.4=.-4`. The same with `5.4`, which comes from `5.0+.4=5.4`. I hope I've helped you! `@Jennifer`